# Normally a function does not have access to a variable defined in another function

Tags: c++

But by using what variable as a parameter, a function may change a variable that is defined in another function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve]. Your question is too broad. Narrow it down with example code.

Comment: Sounds like a question you'd get on a test...

Answer (score 2):

The phrasing of this question suggests it is from a test. Most likely, the intended answer is that declaring a parameter as a *reference* provides access to the passed object.

Access to an object can also be obtained by any means that provides its address. For things passed through parameters, this includes:

- Pass a pointer.
- Pass (the address of) some helper function that returns a pointer or reference.
- Pass a pointer or reference to an object with a known relation to the object (for example, pass a pointer to the first element of the array and the index of the array element to be accessed).
- Pass an integer or string properly converted from a pointer, so that it may be converted back.